# Why does static modifier output is not consistent through function calls?

Tags: c++

I'm revisiting static modifier concepts and I'm wondering why this is the output:

```
this is main()
i is 6
i is 43
i is 44
i is 43
```

for the following code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

void func() 
{

    static int i = 5;
    printf("i is %d\n", ++i);
    i = 42;
    printf("i is %d\n", ++i);
}

int main()
{
    puts("this is main()");
    func();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that static means one variable per instance (at least in Java). Therefore, I understand the first three lines of the output, but then why does the static `int` variable jumps right back to have a value of 44 and then ...it goes backwards and the last value is 43?

I would assume when the first function call ends then the static variable gets out of scope, but it doesn't. Neither it gets reassigned to be value of 5. I might be looking at something pretty obvious here, but I simply don't understand.

Comment: `static` local variables get initialized the **first time** the function is called. They start out with their most recent value on subsequent calls. If they didn't do this they would be exactly like non-static local variables, hence, pointless.

Comment: Because you re-assign `i = 42`. The last `printf` will always print `43`

Comment: Start your debugger, watch `i`, step through `func`, and you will see.

Comment: @NickyC That would be useful if I had a compiler at hand, which I don't have ...

Comment: Without a compiler at hand, how do you compile your program and obtain this observation?

Comment: I'm curious for the negative vote to my question. Yes I'm a new member of SO, but how can I prevent down votes in the future?  I think my question and doubt was legitimate.

Comment: I'm watching C++ Essential Training on Lynda.com. This example code appears in Chapter 2 'Using automatic and static variables'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int i = 5;
```

...is executed on the first call only. But

```
i = 42;
```

...sets `i`'s value to `42` each time you call `func()`.

Comment: Ok so `static int i = 5;` gets called once, but then it does not have an effect on further calls to the function?

Comment: @NellMartinez `static int i = 5;` sets `i`'s value to `5` only on the first call, but it does not prevent `i = 42`. `i`'s value is never changed back to `5`, but it's changed back to `42` during each call.

Comment: Maybe you should add that the value is mantained between calls, to explain the third line of the output.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. I feel so silly. That's the major difference between static and non-static variable. If I'm able to overwrite the declaration of a static variable...then it is simply not static, as @Peter Becker points out in the comment sections.